# Error connecting to the udisks daemon issue inside the container

Tags: ubuntu, containers, podman

I need to run the command udisksctl inside a podman container.

podman run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse -ti localhost/yogi-img:0.4
testuser@2a7dceff581b:/app$ udisksctl loop-setup -f ${efiboot_img} --no-user-interaction
Error connecting to the udisks daemon: Could not connect: No such file or directory
testuser@2a7dceff581b:/app$

Any ideas what is needed here?

That command is working fine on the host which is based on Ubuntu 22.04